# JavaFX - Intercept Drag Events from "child" pannable ScrollPane and redirect to "parent" ScrollPane

Tags: java, javafx, mouseevent, javafx-8

I am trying to accomplish "intercepting" drag events from one pannable ScrollPane (the "child") and re-direct that event to another ScrollPane (the "parent").

Here is my attempt at doing so:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Point2D;
import javafx.scene.Cursor;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application
{
    private final Image PARENT_IMAGE = new Image("http://www.tolkien.co.uk/file/IfbTdA8/5d04a105-e66b-4d9b-b218-928c691eb83d.jpg");
    private final Image CHILD_IMAGE = new Image("http://knightly-slumber.com/worldofwarcraft/files/ScreenShot00019.jpg");

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception
    {
        stage.setTitle("ScrollPane Sync");

        // Set up the scene (two ScrollPanes, both pannable)
        final ScrollPane parentScrollPane = new ScrollPane();
        final ScrollPane childScrollPane = new ScrollPane();
        parentScrollPane.setPrefSize(600, 400);
        childScrollPane.setPrefSize(200, 200);
        parentScrollPane.setContent(new ImageView(PARENT_IMAGE));
        childScrollPane.setContent(new ImageView(CHILD_IMAGE));
        parentScrollPane.setPannable(true);
        childScrollPane.setPannable(true);
        parentScrollPane.setHbarPolicy(ScrollPane.ScrollBarPolicy.NEVER);
        parentScrollPane.setVbarPolicy(ScrollPane.ScrollBarPolicy.NEVER);
        childScrollPane.setHbarPolicy(ScrollPane.ScrollBarPolicy.NEVER);
        childScrollPane.setVbarPolicy(ScrollPane.ScrollBarPolicy.NEVER);
        parentScrollPane.setCursor(Cursor.MOVE);
        childScrollPane.setCursor(Cursor.MOVE);
        VBox root = new VBox(parentScrollPane, childScrollPane);
        root.setPrefSize(800, 600);

        // Make childScrollPane sync with parentScrollPane's h and v-values
        childScrollPane.hvalueProperty().bind(parentScrollPane.hvalueProperty());
        childScrollPane.vvalueProperty().bind(parentScrollPane.vvalueProperty());

        // Attempt to intercept drag events from childScrollPane and re-direct to parentScrollPane
        childScrollPane.addEventFilter(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DRAGGED, event ->
        {
            // re-map x,y coords relative position from child to parent (as they are different sizes). 
            // In other words, if the drag event happened 40% of the way "across" (from the left) and 60% 
            // "down" (from the top) the child pane, then re-map those relative positions to absolute 
            // positions in terms of the parent pane (40% across and 60% down the parent pane).
            double xRelative = event.getX() / childScrollPane.getViewportBounds().getWidth();
            double xInParent = xRelative * parentScrollPane.getViewportBounds().getWidth();
            double yRelative = event.getY() / childScrollPane.getViewportBounds().getHeight();
            double yInParent = yRelative * parentScrollPane.getViewportBounds().getHeight();

            Point2D screenCoords = parentScrollPane.localToScreen(xInParent, yInParent);

            MouseEvent redirectedEvent = new MouseEvent(
                    parentScrollPane, root,
                    MouseEvent.MOUSE_DRAGGED, xInParent, yInParent,
                    screenCoords.getX(), screenCoords.getY(), event.getButton(), event.getClickCount(),
                    event.isShiftDown(), event.isControlDown(), event.isAltDown(), event.isMetaDown(),
                    event.isPrimaryButtonDown(), event.isMiddleButtonDown(), event.isSecondaryButtonDown(),
                    event.isSynthesized(), event.isPopupTrigger(), event.isStillSincePress(),
                    event.getPickResult()
            );

            MouseEvent.fireEvent(parentScrollPane, redirectedEvent);
            event.consume();
        });

        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

I have a VBox (the root of the stage) with two ScrollPanes. Both ScrollPanes are pannable. In this case, I designate the top (and larger) ScrollPane the parent ScrollPane, and the bottom (and smaller) Scrollpane the child ScrollPane. I bind the h and v-values of the child ScrollPane to the parent ScrollPane, so that when one drags/pans in the parent ScrollPane, the child ScrollPane also moves. Then I attempt to add an event filter for `MouseEvent.MOUSE_DRAGGED` events so that we can "intercept" drag events on the parent ScrollPane. Then I attempt to re-direct what that event and re-cast it in terms of the parent ScrollPane, and then fire this new event, and consume the old one.

Currently, panning the parent ScrollPane causes the child ScrollPane to also move (this is good) but nothing happens when dragging in the child ScrollPane (we want both ScrollPane's to move in this case).

One might ask: Why don't you just use a bi-directional binding for the h and v-values for the two ScrollPanes? The reason I want to avoid doing so is it breaks the parent->child relationship I am trying to maintain. In other words, I want all panning to "come from" and be controlled by the parent ScrollPane.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to redirect children events to the parent scrollpane by doing this :

```
// Catch events on scrollPane's children
@FXML
public void press(MouseEvent event) {
    ScrollPane sp = (ScrollPane) ((Node) event.getSource()).getParent().getParent().getParent().getParent();

    PickResult pr = new PickResult(sp.getContent(), event.getSceneX(), event.getSceneY());
    MouseEvent event2 = new MouseEvent(sp, sp.getContent(), event.getEventType(), event.getX(), event.getY(), event.getScreenX(), event.getScreenY(), event.getButton(), event.getClickCount(), event.isShiftDown(), event.isControlDown(), event.isAltDown(), event.isMetaDown(), event.isPrimaryButtonDown(), event.isMiddleButtonDown(), event.isSecondaryButtonDown(), event.isSynthesized(), event.isPopupTrigger(), event.isStillSincePress(), pr);
    sp.getContent().fireEvent(event2);
}

@FXML
public void drag(MouseEvent event) {
    ScrollPane sp = (ScrollPane) ((Node) event.getSource()).getParent().getParent().getParent().getParent();

    PickResult pr = new PickResult(sp.getContent(), event.getSceneX(), event.getSceneY());
    MouseEvent event2 = new MouseEvent(sp, sp.getContent(), event.getEventType(), event.getX(), event.getY(), event.getScreenX(), event.getScreenY(), event.getButton(), event.getClickCount(), event.isShiftDown(), event.isControlDown(), event.isAltDown(), event.isMetaDown(), event.isPrimaryButtonDown(), event.isMiddleButtonDown(), event.isSecondaryButtonDown(), event.isSynthesized(), event.isPopupTrigger(), event.isStillSincePress(), pr);
    sp.getContent().fireEvent(event2);
}

// drag detected => cursor changes
@FXML
public void dragDetected(MouseEvent event) {
    ScrollPane sp = (ScrollPane) ((Node) event.getSource()).getParent().getParent().getParent().getParent();

    PickResult pr = new PickResult(sp.getContent(), event.getSceneX(), event.getSceneY());
    MouseEvent event2 = new MouseEvent(sp, sp.getContent(), event.getEventType(), event.getX(), event.getY(), event.getScreenX(), event.getScreenY(), event.getButton(), event.getClickCount(), event.isShiftDown(), event.isControlDown(), event.isAltDown(), event.isMetaDown(), event.isPrimaryButtonDown(), event.isMiddleButtonDown(), event.isSecondaryButtonDown(), event.isSynthesized(), event.isPopupTrigger(), event.isStillSincePress(), pr);
    sp.getContent().fireEvent(event2);
}
```

Hope it will help.